# Can we get a little bit more detail on most close votes panel under tools?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, 10k-tools

[Close votes panel under tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last2days), we have something like this.

[alt text http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/4701/mostvotescounts.jpg](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/4701/mostvotescounts.jpg)

Current active close votes for first question is 0 actually (its closed and reopened),

So, can we get current active votes count in bracket like this?

```
5 (0) The best tools money can buy
```

Comment: Good point, sometimes old votes stick around

Comment: Yeah, I saw **7** votes a few days ago, but 5 is even more confusing...

Comment: [We stopped showing old votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61715/moderator-close-vote-list-shows-more-than-5-close-votes/80484#80484) altogether. I guess it's arguable whether that means [status-completed] or [status-declined], so ping me if you want the other one :)

Comment: no problem @balpha, status-completed is positive thinking, thats better :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Only currently open questions show in that list.
- The list only counts votes cast in the selected time period
- The list shows the total number votes (subject to the above) so you can find the close history by 1) selecting a long time 2) computing integer V/5 for number of times closed, and V%5 for currently active close votes

Similar remarks apply to the votes to repoen list.

No more information is needed.

BTW- This is all the result of observation and deduction. I have no official word on the matter.

Comment: +1 for info, and that `V%5` could clear some confusions.

Comment: May be I will do myself with greasemonkey later :-)