# Moderator close vote list shows more than 5 close votes

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions, 10k-tools

Why am I seeing close vote counts higher than 5 on the moderator tools section of Gaming?

[image: Example]

If this is showing total close votes over two days I think it'd be more useful to show only current close votes (so I can tell where I can get a close with one vote).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38907/can-we-get-a-little-bit-more-detail-on-most-close-votes-panel-under-tools

Answer (score 7):

You are correct that it is the total close votes. That question was closed with 5 votes first. Then it was reopened. 2 more votes have been added since then. The one beneath it with 5 there is specifically a reopened question as well.

These are live votes or cleared votes, by the way. It will not track votes that aged away, so you can traditionally figure out the current live votes by subtracting the highest multiple of five.

Comment: `votes % 5`? (15)

Comment: It's a little more muddy than this since a moderator can cast a binding close vote, which only tallies as 1 vote. So a close count of 7 could mean many things. For example, the question could have been originally closed on 3 votes (2 normal, 1 mod), reopened, and then had 4 additional close votes added. That being said, most of the time it does end up being 5 normal close votes at a time, at least here on Meta.

Comment: @Jon That's why I said "traditionally". Casting binding votes on Gaming, I'm well aware that it skews the count, but in most circumstances we diamonds won't vote until the last, if at all.

Answer (score 2):

We now restrict those lists to close votes that are actually meaningful. I think it's enough if these open/close war question show up in both the "recently reopened" *and* the "recent close votes".