# How has someone voted to delete a recently closed question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-delete

At the time of this writing, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75217/first-tag-in-title-is-very-inconvienent) was written 57 minutes ago, closed 43 *seconds* ago and has already earned itself one delete vote:

[image: mod tools page showing one delete vote]

According to [the FAQ page about deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean), there's only one scenario in which posts earn delete votes: when they've been closed for more than 48 hours. So how did someone vote to delete?

Here's some good old-fashioned wild speculation:

- <del>after question is closed, OP's right to delete unilaterally gets converted to the right to cast one delete vote not bound by the 48-hour timer</del> **EDIT**: this guess is wrong, per that question's OP
- based on the comment and revision history, it looks like the OP deleted and then undeleted the question shortly after it was asked; this might be some kind of unintentional aftereffect of that deletion

Comment: (If a moderator —or even developer?— feels an urgent need for testing: 10 hours ago I deleted a duplicate question [I posted myself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75175/profile-page-is-missing-buttons-for-sort-order-if-less-than-3-items-on-a-page), after 2 others and I myself cast a close vote. Feel free to temporarily undelete that and see if it automatically converts my delete action into a delete vote. I cannot see that question myself anymore.)

Comment: @Arjan As I point out in my answer, there's no conversion of anything. Just undeleting it will register, closed or not, because there is now a question with one successful delete vote that is not currently deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was my question. I deleted it almost immediately after the link to the duplicate was provided. I must have accidentally hit undelete on a subsequent page thinking it wasn't deleted yet.

After coming back to the site and seeing it was now marked as `closed`, I was unable to delete it as a message stating

> To allow for possible reopneing, you
>   may delete in 2 days

was showing up when I hit delete.

Answer (score 3):

Your second guess is mostly on the spot. This is the same situation that [happened here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67968/un-delete-count-off/67970#67970) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72289/re-open-votes-on-a-question-which-doesnt-have-any-re-open-votes). [Here is a related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61715/moderator-close-vote-list-shows-more-than-5-close-votes) which explains why things happen the way they do. It's not so much unintentional as it is confusing.

It has one *successful* delete vote, cast before the closing happened. Because that successful delete vote was in the past 2 days and the question is currently not deleted, you'll see it in the recent delete votes. There are no live delete votes on that question.